# where clause without single quote in set?

Tags: sql, sql-server, single-quotes

I have a set statement. I am trying to add a where statement inside that. However, when I put a single quote, it is not executing. How to escape the single quote in where clause to execute the set statement? Below is my code:

```
DECLARE @desttablename NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @desttablename = 'select distinct desttablename 
from #table_norm 
where desttablename = 'Screener''
```

Comment: You escape single quotes by doubling them.

Comment: i tried but not working when i execute the statement

Comment: What's the error that you got?

Comment: tried this SET @desttablename = 'select distinct desttablename from #table_norm where desttablename = ''screener'''  Got an error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'distinct'.

Comment: Try simply doing a select on your string first. That will show you what you are getting

Comment: @JonathanWillcock tried with double single quotes but the error is Incorrect syntax near 'screener'.

Comment: Use a parameter and the embedded apostrophe delimiters are eliminated.

Comment: In your query it will break so alternatively you can double the single quote to fix the issue, try something like `SET @desttablename = 'select distinct desttablename from #table_norm  where desttablename = '+'''Screener'''+'' `

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative way to do this:

```
select @desttablename = (select distinct desttablename from #table_norm where 
desttablename = 'Screener')
```